# Slow LAN communication from one VM to another (Hyper V, 2019 Standard, MySQL DB)

Tags: mysql, remote-desktop, windows-server-2019

We have an accounting software that works on MySQL DB. To make it run better, we got a new powerful server and put two VMs on it. One with DB and another one with RDS.

When I try to run our application via UNC path from the DB machine, it works great. But when I try to run the same on RDS server, it took about 3-6x more time to start.

I turned off firewall and antivirus software, and don't know what should I do next. Machines as is work great, we have no issues.

I tested entirely clean machine and I don't get any startup lag. I even installed terminal server on that machine to see what happens, and all is the same. I followed every step I did on other server and got better results, meaning I can't replicate.

Is there a way to see/measure what is happening with the program and LAN when I am trying to start the app?

Comment: You could enable your General Log in your configuration.  Remember to login as root and turn it OFF with SET GLOBAL general_log=0;  once you are started to avoid filling your media.   Change your configuration to general_log=0   for the future restarts of instance, until you need logging beginning with start of instance. Good Luck.  View profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.

Comment: Weirdest thing is that when the app is run as 64 bit application, it runs great. But as 32 bit one the startup takes ages. Thanks for the tips!